# HTML/CSS elements not resizing with the web page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been into HTML/CSS lately and have been designing a web page. I have been searching for hours on here and on Google as well as completely rewritten my code from scratch. It has been incredibly annoying.

Every other element on my web page will resize and reposition itself to fit the new window size, except the `about` element, which is just sitting in the same spot as the window is being resized as though it has been given a fixed position, but that is not the case (at least I don't think it is). Can you please take a look at my code and tell me any reasons why this might be happening?

(Please note all information has been removed for privacy reasons.)

```css
charset"utf-8";

#container{
width:900px;
}

#image{
position: relative;
padding-top:50px;
padding-right: 500px;
}

#title{
position: relative;
bottom: 275;
left: 250;
height: 100px;
width: 400px;
}

#margin{
margin-left:10;
}

#about{
position: relative;
bottom: 300;
left: 820;
height: 500px;
width: 350px;
border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
} 

@font-face { 
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(font.ttf);
} 

#header { 
width: 900px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
background-color: #787878;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
font-family: myFirstFont;
} 

#footer { 
background-color: #FFD700;
height:20px;
left:0;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
} 

.button{text-decoration:none; text-align:center;
 padding:11px 32px;
 border:solid 1px #004F72;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#E5FFFF;
 background-color:#3BA4C7;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0% ,#1982A5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982A5', endColorstr='#1982A5',GradientType=0 );
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0% ,#1982A5 100%);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;

  }.button:hover{
 padding:11px 32px;
 border:solid 1px #004F72;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#E5FFFF;
 background-color:#3BA4C7;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0% ,#1982A5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982A5', endColorstr='#1982A5',GradientType=0 );
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0% ,#1982A5 100%);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Removed</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#800000">
<center>
<font color="#FFD700">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<font size="16">Removed</font>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="button"/>Home</a>
<a href="#" class="button"/>About</a>
</div>
<div id="image"><img src="Removed" width="500"></div>
<div id="title"><h1>Welcome to My Website!</h1></div>
</center>
<div id="about"><p>About information removed.</p></div>
</font>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put this into a JSFiddle or CodePen? Also, do you mean its position isn't changing? Or that its size isn't changing?

Comment: First of all, you should run your code through a validator. Some end tags are in the wrong position.

Comment: You hae some very last millenium style HTML going on there. You shouldn't be using `font` or `center` elements. All style belongs into the style sheet and use less divs and more semantic HTML elements such as `h1`, `h2`, etc. for headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#about` div stays put because it's positioned inside `#container`, which has a fixed width and lacks styling to center it in the page.

If you want the container to stay in the center of the page as you adjust the browser width, give `#container` automatic margins on the left and right:

```
#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

The container's `position: relative;` attribute allows its children to be positioned absolutely within the container, like this:

```
#about {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

I've made a snippet that demonstrates this approach and makes a number of other improvements.

```css
@charset"utf-8";

body {
  background: #800000;
  color: #ffd700;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.navigation {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #ffd700;
  border: 1px dotted #ffd700;
}
.navigation a:hover {
  background: #ffd700;
  color: #800000;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 310px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">

    <div class="banner"> Banner </div>

    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#"/>About</a>
    </div>

  </div><!--end header -->

  <h1> Welcome to My Website! </h1>

  <div id="content">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Pebuildingtrojan.jpg" alt="liberty">
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <p> Information about this website. </p>
  </div>

</div><!--end container -->
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It moves when I looked at it in Safari. Could be that you're missing `px` in some measurements. Also, as @RoToRa mentioned in his comment, you're using **really** old coding methods; if you're currently learning this - find a better source because that one is doing you more harm than good.

Change

```
#about{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300; // missing the px
    left: 820;   // missing the px
```

to

```
#about{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 820px;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Lister mentioned, there are some problems with the markup. But, going with the resize and positioning mentioned in your question, here are some places to start...

**HTML Tags**

Avoid inline styling in the HTML. Things like font color should be done in the CSS, not within an HTML tag. Check out the [HTML5 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) for more on clean markup and styling.

**Positioning**

You used a wrapper element, which is good. Child elements - `divs` with `relative` positions will stay within the flow of the document. To get elements to resize, you have to use variable widths, not pixel widths. For instance, you have:

```
#about {
  position: relative;
  width:350px;
  /* rest of code */
}
```

When the window is resized, the `#about` section *always* keeps a width of 350px. To have it resize, use an equivalent percent value. Since your container is 900px, use:

```
#about {
  position: relative;
  width: 38%;
  /* rest of code */
}
```

You also need to go through and make sure your position values have 'px' in the value. For instance:

```
#title{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 275;
  left: 250;
}
```

...should be...

```
#title{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 275px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

Lastly your `#footer` has `absolute` position which takes it out of the flow of the document.